# Bootstrap Dropdown in Navbar is not working with NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dropdown, bootstrap-5

The Dropdown doesn't open up on click.
I'm using bootstrap 5 on nextjs 12.

I tried adding the CDN links, but it doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

In the app.js I imported bootstrap.css

**_app.js**

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

In the Index.js I added the CDN.

**index.js**

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Script from "next/script";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
      <Header />
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
      </Head>
      <Script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" />
      <div className="px-4 py-5 my-5 text-center flex-grow-1">
        <h1 className="display-5 fw-bold">Next.js + Bootstrap ❤️</h1>
       
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </main>
  );
}
```

**Header.js**

```
    const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header className="p-3 bg-dark text-white">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="d-flex  flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start ">
         <ul className="nav col-12 col-lg-auto ms-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0  "> 
            <li className="nav-item dropdown">
              <a href="#" className="nav-link px-2 text-white dropdown-toggle">
                Services
              </a>
              <div className="dropdown-menu">
                <a href="#" className="dropdown-item">
                  React
                </a>
                <a href="#" className="dropdown-item">Test</a>
              </div>
            </li>      
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};
export default Header;
```

Comment: The script element in the Home function looks strange to me: I'd change it to have a closing tag: <script ...></script>.

Answer (score 2):

Please visit this [tutorial](https://myas92.medium.com/how-to-create-navbar-in-next-with-bootstrap-10713b65a56b), which helps you add navbar with bootstrap to a react or nextjs project

**Don't use cdn link of bootstrap for using navbar in React project**

You can use [React bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) framework, to add navbar

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

Add the stylesheet to the `app.js` file

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

And create a navbar component like the below code

```
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                Another action
              </NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
                Separated link
              </NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}

export default BasicExample;
```

Answer (score 1):

step-1 : import bootstrap css in **_app.js**

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

step-2  import bootstrap js in **_app.js**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

useEffect(() => {
    require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js");
  }, []);
```

final code looks like :

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import '@/styles/globals.css'

config.autoAddCss = false;

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js");
  }, []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```